# How to solve " *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated " in colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo

```
!rm darknet
!make 
!./darknet detector train yolo.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show
```

When I train my dataset on yolov4 using darknet in colab, I received this error:

```
CUDA-version: 11000 (11020), cuDNN: 7.6.5, GPU count: 1  
OpenCV version: 3.2.0
yolov4-custom
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

I don't understand why this error exists, just a week ago, no problem when running code

Comment: Could you please show the full code?

Comment: this is my code link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hXufu9-t86eJUYL5TeZdUkneV6_Ngt9e?usp=sharing
And this is my drive i mounted: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HN8vmt8-AihHyY5QEekmJjdsqqcT0neD?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't access your drive folder. Did you follow the instructions here? https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-compile-on-linux-using-make

Comment: Thank for your support! I solved this error by using python 3.8 instead of 3.7